# Limiting LaserScan range for Map Building

Tags: navigation, mapping, rplidar, turtlebot, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a turtlebot and RPLidar A2 sensor. I am currently implementing hector slam and I am wondering if it is possible to use the laserScans registered just from the 180degree rotation facing the front of the robot instead of the entire 360deg the RPLidar has to build the map. Is there a way to go about doing that?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255110/limiting-laserscan-range-for-map-building/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2017-02-20**:
Try setting the map_update_angle_thresh, laser_min_dist, laser_max_dist params in the hector_slam launch file. Again this is just a logical guess.

**Comment by [tb12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29230/tb12/) on 2017-02-23**:
Which slam algorithm are you using?

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-24**:
I am using Hector SLAM.

**Comment by [skydddive](https://answers.ros.org/users/36186/skydddive/) on 2018-07-01**:
in ros,there is a laserfilter package for it.You can use the laserscanangleboundfilters to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed to limit the scan by editing the hector mapping source file,`hectorMappingRos.cpp`. Set a fixed range for [i] - for the scan range and pointcloud data container from 270-360deg and 0 to 90deg. However, this gave rise to an exponential increase in inaccuracies in map building.

---

Originally posted by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) with karma: 62 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-23**:
what errors did you get? I would expect the accuracy to decrease - less data points - but Hector SLAM will work with XTION - although from experience it's don't like swift angle changes too much as it looses track (Can be helped by adding IMU data)

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-23**:
I am only using a 2D RPLidar A2 sensor, which might decrease the inaccuracies further. I usually get the common `SearchDir angle change too large` which then messes up the map building process. It's somewhat similar to what I described in my other [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/255216/laser-filter-and-hector-mapping-issue/)

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-23**:
I am also adding a fixed tilt of 20deg to the sensor (which is why I am limiting my sensor to 180deg), but this also worsens the map building process. Tried implementing [this](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_ortho_projector) but that itself doesn't seem to be working properly

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-23**:
Yep you will get "SearchDir angle change too large" if the robot rotates too swiftly and there are not enough data points. My 2D RPLidar A2 works fine, but I haven't restricted it

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-23**:
Yup, it works best with no restrictions. Thanks for your help Mark!

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-25**:
I wondered what that error message meant

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's not documented on the [laser_pipeline](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline) and [laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters) pages, but `laser_filters` actually contains a `LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter` which seems to do exactly what you are after (from [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_filters/blob/9c0c366816cb3889bb3d3afb4862f4cae9e4a47e/laser_filters_plugins.xml#L33-L38)):

> This is a filter that removes points in a laser scan outside of certain angular bounds.

It shouldn't be too hard to set this up. See #q61538 for a related Q&A.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-24**:
Nice find! :)

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-24**:
Yup I used that filter prior to directly tweaking `Hector Slam`. I posted a [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/255216/laser-filter-and-hector-mapping-issue/) regarding that filter and the error I got. Soon realized that tweaking `hector mapping` directly also gave similar errors. Guess it's a limitation of hector mapping.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-25**:
@Rayner: I don't really mind, but could you please include some notes on the approaches that you've already tried in your question text? That would avoid posters spending time on something you've alreay tried.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-25**:
So are you saying this does not work for hector slam

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2017-02-25**:
There is also `LaserScanAngularBoundsFilterInPlace` to remove an arbitrary chuck, instead of changing the start and stop angles:
https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_filters/blob/indigo-devel/include/laser_filters/angular_bounds_filter_in_place.h

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-26**:
@burf2000 It limits the performance of Hector SLAM. A 180deg range still works quite well provided the sensor is level and the robot moves  and rotates slowly